# Fortran & OpenMP: How to declare and allocate an allocatable THREADPRIVATE array

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran, fortran90

I had a serial code where I would declare a bunch of variables in modules and then `use` those modules across the rest of my program and subroutines. Now I am trying to parallelize this code. There is a portion of the code that I want to run in parallel which seems to be working except for one array, `gtmp`. I want each thread to have it's own version of `gtmp` and I want that version to be private to its respective thread, so I've used the `threadprivate` directive. `gtmp` is only used inside the parallel region of the code or within subroutines that are only called from the parallel part of the code.

At first I allocated `gtmp` in a serial portion of the code before the parallel portion, but that was an issue because then only the master thread 'version' of `gtmp` got allocated and the other thread 'versions' of `gtmp` had a `size` of `1` rather than the expected allocated size of `gtmp`, (this was shown by the "test" `print` statement). I think this happened because the master thread is the only thread executing code in the serial portions. So, I moved the `allocate` line into the parallel region, which allowed all threads to have appropriately sized/allocated `gtmp` arrays, but since my parallel region is inside a loop I get an error when the program tries to allocate `gtmp` a second time in the second iteration of the `r` loop.

Note: elsewhere in the code all the other variables in `mymod` are given values.

Here is a simplified portion of the code that is having the issue:

```
module mymod
  integer :: xBins, zBins, rBins, histCosThBins, histPhiBins, cfgRBins
  real(kind=dp),allocatable :: gtmp(:,:,:)
end module mymod

subroutine compute_avg_force
  use mymod
  implicit none
  integer :: r, i, j, ip
  integer :: omp_get_thread_num, tid

  ! I used to allocate 'gtmp' here.

  do r = 1, cfgRBins
    !$omp PARALLEL DEFAULT( none ) &
    !$omp PRIVATE( ip, i, j, tid ) &
    !$omp SHARED( r, xBins, zBins, histCosThBins, histPhiBins )
    allocate( gtmp(4,0:histCosThBins+1,0:histPhiBins+1) )
    tid = omp_get_thread_num()  !debug
    print*, 'test', tid, histCosThBins, histPhiBins, size(gtmp)
    !$omp DO SCHEDULE( guided )
    do ip = 1, (xBins*zBins)
        call subroutine_where_i_alter_gtmp(...)
            ...code to be executed in parallel using gtmp...
    end do !ip
    !$omp END DO
    !$omp END PARALLEL
end do !r
end subroutine compute_avg_force
```

So, the issue is coming from the fact that I need all threads to be active, (ie. in a parallel region), to appropriately initialize all 'versions' of `gtmp` but my parallel region is inside a loop and I can't allocate `gtmp` more than once.

In short, what is the correct way to allocate `gtmp` in this code? I've thought that I could just make another `omp parallel` region before the loop and use that to allocate `gtmp` but that seems clunky so I'm wondering what the "right" way to do something like this is.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In a rush but either deallocate and reallocate, or  almost certainly better move the parallel region outside the outer loop, adjusting scoping appropriately, and allocate once outside the loop as you did before. AND DON'T USE REAL(8) - see here passim

Comment: I can't move the parallel region outside the `r` loop for efficiency reasons. Don't worry I don't use REAL(8). I wrote that because I have another module where I set my precisions and I didn't want to make my post longer by putting that in it too. I'll edit to reflect what the initialization line actually looks like.

Comment: I think you can replace the allocate outside of the parallel region and declare `gtmp` as threadprivate. Add `copyin(gtmp)` to get the "master" status of `gtmp` to be propagated. This might be inefficient though and there are other solutions: allocate an array of arrays, each of which used by a single thread, or again allocate in the parallel region. Are the results for `r+1` dependent on `r`?

Comment: Okay, any idea of how that compares, efficiency wise, to making another parallel region before the `r` loop and just `allocate`ing there? No the results for `r+1` are independent of `r`.